# Memory leak on reflect_on_all_associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to track down a memory leak in my Rails app. I know using reflect_on_all_associations is a bit slow, but has anyone found this to cause a memory leak in Rails apps? I'm using 3.2.6. Also generally is it frowned upon to use reflect_on_all_associations in a production app?

Something like:

```
Event.reflect_on_all_associations.map{|mac| mac.class_name if mac.macro==:belongs_to}.compact
Event.reflect_on_all_associations.map{|mac| mac.class_name if mac.macro==:has_many}.compact
```

Thanks!